# Algorithm to evaluate a binary expression tree?

Tags: java, recursion

I hate recursion, I can't trace through the code easily, but with trees I don't have a choice.

This is what I've tried so far.

```
private int evaluate(Node n)
{
    if (n != null)
    {
        if (n.isLeaf())  // n is a node with a number
            return Integer.parseInt(n.element);
        else
        {
            int left = evaluate(n.left);
            int right = evaluate(n.right);
            return calculate(left, n.element, right);
        } //end else
    } //end if
} //end evaluate
```

Comment: You did well, all you need is a trivial, non-recursive calcilate to complete your exercise. ...And don't forget a return.

Comment: It would have helped a lot if you also posted the problem you have with your code. It is "Method must return a value".

Comment: The method is returning a value in some cases but compiler don't understand.

Comment: I was messing with the calculate function, can't get it to work the way I want to, but I have the return statement in.  But is the recursion I'm using sound.  I'm pretty new to recursion.

Comment: You need to return a value when `n == null` or throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: You don't need to ever use recursion, you can accomplish anything you want using for-loops. You just need to use a stack to remember your current and parent states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
return calculate(left, n.element, right);
```

I assume your node is an operation, ie "+", "-" etc.

Your "calculate" has to execute the corresponding operation on the int "left" and "right" and you are done!

Comment: Yeah, I'm fixing up that method to calculate.  I know nothing about recursion, so I'm seeing if this works.

Comment: Thanks, I got my calculate method to work and the recursion is working

Answer (score 0):

The method does not provide a valid return for each path. So you need to add `return ...` at the end of the method. I assumed zero would be appropriate since this path should actually never been visited in your recursion.

```
private int evaluate(Node n)
{
    if (n != null)
    {
        if (n.isLeaf())  // n is a node with a number
            return Integer.parseInt(n.element);
        else
        {
            int left = evaluate(n.left);
            int right = evaluate(n.right);
            return calculate(left, n.element, right);
        } //end else
    } //end if
    return 0;
} //end evaluate
```

Apart from this your recursion seems to be in good shape.

Comment: I put that in place, just used 999999 instead of 0.  I figure I'm going to be getting 0 as a legitimate answer while I'm debugging, so 999999 serves as a better guide for that.  But thanks, I just don't trust myself with recursion, so I'm glad I'm starting to get it right.

Comment: As stated by others you could actually throw an exception. Like i said this path should (in what i understand from your code) never actually be visited by your program.

Comment: For the time being, the calculate method has a lot of complexities to it, so for debugging purposes the number works right now